# Python: поиск фрагмента строки в файле и замена всей строки, содержащей его

Tags: python

Есть большой файл с параметрами вида:

```
IP Address = XX.XX.XX.XX

System Function Allowed=1

Operating mode=3

Auth mode=0
```

и так далее. Названия и части названий встречаются не один раз, поэтому configparser работать не хочет. Нужно заменить некоторые параметры, так понимаю, что самый простой способ - поиск в файле по ключевому тексту, например, `Operating mode`, и замена всей строки, содержащей это словосочетание, на, например, заданную `Operating mode=0`. Однако не хватает знаний, как это реализовать.

Пока есть вот это, что успешно меняет строку на строку.

```py
import re

o = open('out.ini','w')

data = open('inp.ini').read()

o = open('out.ini','w')

o.write( re.sub('Software Version=0','Software Version=1',data) )

o.close()
```

Проблема в том, что значения могут меняться и просто подставить полную строку не всегда возможно. Как сделать поиск по фрагменту строки? НЕ по слову, т.к. слова в большинстве случаев будет недостаточно.

Answer (score 0):

Так пойдет? Можно добавить свои замены

```
import re

o = open('out.ini','w')

data = open('inp.ini').read()
data = data.split('\n')

for i in range(len(data)):
    stri = data[i]
    if stri.startswith('Software Version='):
        data[i] = 'Software Version=1'

o = open('out.ini','w')

o.write( '\n'.join(data))

o.close()
```